Error in the master pod while installing Dremio in Kubernentes
I am trying to install Dremio in Kubernetes using Helm (I have followed this guide). As the distirbuted storage, I am using a S3 compatible object store hosted in a Dell EMC PowerScale.
I have some troubles with the master pod (it is the dremio-master-0 pod). In fact, during the inital phase, it returns this error:
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException: Path is a file: s3a://dremio-bucket/uploads

What is the reason for this error? Has anyone experienced a similar issue?
In case it would be helpful, I provide the distirbuted storage configuration values entered in the values file of the Dremio helm chart:
distStorage:
  type: "aws"
  aws:
    bucketName: "dremio-bucket"
    path: "/"
    authentication: "accessKeySecret"
    credentials:
      accessKey: "XXXX"
      secret: "YYYY"
    extraProperties: |
      <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.endpoint</name>
        <value>S3A_ENDPOINT</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.path.style.access</name>
        <value>true</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>dremio.s3.compat</name>
        <value>true</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled</name>
        <value>false</value>
      </property>

Thanks to anyone that will replay.
